# for loop performance of pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I am curious about the fact that, when applying a function to each element of pd.Series inside for loop, the execution time looks significantly faster than O(N).

Considering a function below, which is rotating the number bit-wise, but the code itself is not important here.

```py
def rotate(x: np.uint32) -> np.uint32:
    return np.uint32(x >> 1) | np.uint32((x & 1) << 31)
```

When executing this code 1000 times in a for loop, it simply takes the order of 1000 times as expected.

```py
x = np.random.randint(2 ** 32 - 1, dtype=np.uint32)

%timeit rotate(x)
# 13 µs ± 807 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
for i in range(1000):
    rotate(x)
# 9.61 ms ± 255 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

However when I apply this code inside for loop over a Series of size 1000, it gets significantly faster.

```py
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(2 ** 32 - 1, size=1000, dtype=np.uint32))

%%timeit
for x in s:
    rotate(x)
# 2.08 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I am curious about the mechanism that makes this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note in your first loop you're not actually using the next value of the iterator. The following is a better comparison:

```
...: %%timeit 
...: for i in range(1000):
...:     rotate(i) 
...:                                                                                                 
1.46 ms ± 71.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

...: %%timeit 
...: for x in s: 
...:     rotate(x) 
...:                                                                                                
1.6 ms ± 66.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Not surprisingly, they perform more or less the same.

In your original example, by using a variable `x` declared outside, the interpreter needed to load in that variable using `LOAD_GLOBAL 2 (x)` while if you just used the value `i` then the interpreter could just call `LOAD_FAST 0 (i)`, which as the name hints is faster.

Comment: Thank you, so it is due to how Python interpreter lookup variables rather than a Series specific behavior. It turned clear for my question but let me ask another. When I tried `for x in s.tolist(): rotate(x)` it took 1.79 ms, while `for x in s.value: rotate(x)` took 9.52 ms, which is similar performance as my first example. Where does the difference come from? Is it just because ndarray is not optimal for for loop?

Comment: `s.tolist()` uses the built-in `list_iterator` while `s.values` uses a custom iterator implemented by numpy. It looks like the former is faster indeed.